# upsert in multiple large tables using ssis

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I have 40 tables having different structure in one of DB on one server  that is  being updated by data provider.

I want to create a SSIS package that would pull data from that data provider DB and insert ,update or delete (merge) data in to development ,Test,UAT and prod DBs.

The tables are having 1m- 3m rows and 20-30 columns each and all the DBs are on SQL Server platform and are on different servers.

The business requirement is to load data everyday on a particular time and  have to use SSIS for this. I am new to SSIS and want your suggestions to create better design.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about SSIS.

There are packaged solutions to synch databases.

In general with just TSQL

1. delete
2. update
3. insert

TSQL

```
delete 
tableA a
where not exists (select 1 from tableB b where b.PK = a.PK)

update A  
set ...
from TableA a 
join TableB b 
  on a.PK = b.PK  

insert into TableA (columns) 
select columns 
from tableB b
where not exists (select 1 from tableA a where b.PK = a.PK)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a very broad question. I can help you with pointers. Follow them and ask questions when you get stuck. I'll be telling you for 1 table. You will have to do parallel for others:

1. Create a `source OLEDB connection` and `destination OLEDB connection`. This will be used to copy from source to staging tables where actual Data warehouse sits.
2. Create a `Data flow task`. Simply copy source db to staging tables. You'll have to implement *incremental loading* logic. For instance, store the last source.Id and load data from that Id onwards to latest.
3. Once you've data in staging, create another `Data flow task` where you'll have to apply `Lookup transformation` to insert and update data, while loading in destination table.
4. Deletion won't work here, so you'll have to apply deletion in next step(preferably via `execute sql task`)

Above steps are the guidelines. You'll be having multiple sequence containers working in parallel, each having above DFT, working on separate tables.